# Spring security session expiration

Tags: spring, session, spring-security, session-timeout

1. What is the maximum time of user inactivity (session expiration time) when using spring security?
2. When is session expiration date updated? Does it update when we call `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` ? I.e. what is "user activity" for spring security?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Spring Security relies on session management support provided by servlet containers.

1. Session timeout can be configured in `web.xml`:

   ```
   <session-config>
       <session-timeout>30</session-timeout> <!-- in minutes -->
   </session-config>
   ```

   otherwise container's default value is used. You can override timeout for particular session using `Session.setMaxInactiveInterval()` (in seconds).
2. Session expiration date is updated when any request associated with that session comes in.